# How to update an atom from multiple future(s) in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I was trying to do the following exercise from *Brave Clojure* book:

> Create a function that uses futures to parallelize the task of downloading random quotes from http://www.braveclojure.com/random-quote using `(slurp "http://www.braveclojure.com/random-quote")`. The futures should update an atom that refers to a total word count for all quotes. The function will take the number of quotes to download as an argument and return the atom’s final value. Keep in mind that you’ll need to ensure that all futures have finished before returning the atom’s final value.

This is my solution:

```
(def i (atom {}))
(defn update-vals [map vals f]
(reduce #(update-in % [%2] f) map vals))
(defn incifnil [x] (if (nil? x) 1 (inc x)))
(require '[clojure.string :as str])
(defn splitwords [s] (str/split s #"\W"))
(defn word-counting [map s] (update-vals map (splitwords s) incifnil))
(defn update-i [s] (swap! i word-counting s))
(defn bring-quote [] (slurp "https://www.braveclojure.com/random-quote"))
(defn future-creator [] (future (update-i (bring-quote))))
(defn list_of_futures [n] (map (fn [_] (future-creator)) (range n)))
(defn checkall-futures [future-list] (map deref future-list))
(defn quote-word-count [n] (do
                            (checkall-futures (list_of_futures n))
                            @i))
```

But if I try to take the last value of atom i from the REPL I take an empty map.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides using `run!`, another handy trick is to use `mapv` in place of `map` everywhere.  `mapv` always produces a vector result and is not lazy.  This removes many lazy/timing related problems when debugging, especially at the REPL.

Be sure to always study [the Clojure Cheatsheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet).  There is also a good list of [documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) available at this [template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Answer (score 3):

`map` in your `checkall-futures` is lazy.  You need something that forces the `deref` on all items.  E.g. use `run!` instead of `map` there.

Comment: Wow, all this time and I've never encountered `run!` before....  I could have used that just yesterday!